# IntelliJ console cannot be coloured on Windows

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, logging, intellij-plugin

I tried all the suggested steps, but my console is not colorful. Here is what I applied:

***logback.xml:*** on the project root

```
<configuration debug="true">
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <!-- On Windows machines setting withJansi to true enables ANSI
                color code interpretation by the Jansi library. This requires
                org.fusesource.jansi:jansi:1.8 on the class path.  Note that
                Unix-based operating systems such as Linux and Mac OS X
                support ANSI color codes by default. -->
        <withJansi>true</withJansi>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>[%thread] %highlight(%-5level) %cyan(%logger{15}) - %msg %n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

***application.yml:***

```
spring:
  output:
    ansi:
      enabled: ALWAYS

logging:
  pattern:
    console: %clr("%d %-5level %logger : %msg%n")
    file: "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"

  level:
    org.springframework: error
    org.hibernate: error
    com.company: debug
```

So, what is missing? (I use Windows 10).

Comment: `spring:
  output:
    ansi:
      enabled: always` , maybe use lower case `always` ?

Comment: I tried, but does not make any sense. There is a problem on `console: %clr("%d %-5level %logger : %msg%n")`. It gives "It is forbidden to specify block composed value at the same line as key" error.

Comment: Please remove `<withJansi>true</withJansi>`

Comment: mini config test is only set `spring:   output:     ansi:       enabled: always` is enough. You don't need `logback.xml` or others. In IDEA, when you start spring boot app, console will show color output.

Comment: Have you tried it on a Windows machine? It is not working even with / without logback.xml.

Comment: @life888888 Do you have any idea amigo?

Comment: (1)Yes, I  tried it on a Windows machine. (2) I use https://start.spring.io/ build demo app (3) Unzip demo.zip (4) Run IDEA then use IDEA open demo (5) application.properties default is empty. (6) add `spring.output.ansi.enabled=always` to application.properties (7) Run `DemoApplication` in IDEA, then you can IDEA console output color log.

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort. You solved the issues, I created a new project and made it worked . Then, I tried to comment out some part in my project and found guillty one. THis line --> `logging:
  pattern:
#    console: "%d %-5level %logger : %msg%n"` So, what is wrong with this line and how should I update?

Comment: (1) `logging.pattern.console=%clr(%d %-5level %logger : %msg%n)` will output all green. (2) `logging.pattern.console=%clr(%d{yy-MM-dd E HH:mm:ss.SSS}){blue} %clr(%-5p) %clr(${PID}){faint} %clr(---){faint} %clr([%8.15t]){cyan} %clr(%-40.40logger{0}){blue} %clr(:){red} %clr(%m){faint}%n` COPY FROM  https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-boot/logging-console-pattern.html

Comment: It works good, thanks a lot amigo. Voted+